# I am attempting to obtain data from text file that is identified by the line above

Tags: python

As I mentioned I am attempting to create a python script for data analysis. It is not displaying the data in the next line for the loading of the specific species which I denoted as the 8th value of the next line of the line starting with TIP4P.

```
ifile = open(iFileName,"r")
x = 0
while True:
    vals=ifile.readline().split()
    if (vals==[]):
        empties += 1
        if (empties > 10):
            break
    else:
        empties = 0
       # print vals
        try:
            if (vals[0]=="(TIP4P)"):
              next(vals[0]=="absolute")
              x = float(vals[8].rstrip(")"))
              print x
        except:
            pass
print p, "\t", x
```

I have attached an image of the data as well. This an attempt at specify a working script which I placed below.

```
ifile = open(iFileName,"r")
    x = 0
    while True:
        vals=ifile.readline().split()
        if (vals==[]):
            empties += 1
            if (empties > 10):
                break
        else:
            empties = 0
           # print vals
            try:
                if (vals[0]=="absolute"):
                    x = float(vals[8].rstrip(")"))
                    print x
            except:
                pass
    print p, "\t", x
```

```
oadings per component:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Component 0 (TIP4P), current number of integer/fractional/reaction molecules: 28/0/0 (avg.  28.00000), density:  47.96742 (avg.  47.96742) [kg/m^3]
    absolute adsorption:   3.50000 (avg.   3.50000) [mol/uc],   2.0371090732 (avg.   2.0371090732) [mol/kg],  38.7523740627 (avg.  38.7523740627) [mg/g]
                          45.6597133610 (avg.  45.6597133610) [cm^3 STP/g],   56.5172296926 (avg.  56.5172296926) [cm^3 STP/cm^3]
    excess adsorption:     3.5000000000 (avg.   3.5000000000) [mol/uc],   2.0371090732 (avg.   2.0371090732) [mol/kg],  38.7523740627 (avg.  38.7523740627) [mg/g]
                          45.6597133610 (avg.  45.6597133610) [cm^3 STP/g],   56.5172296926 (avg.  56.5172296926) [cm^3 STP/cm^3]
Component 1 (CO2), current number of integer/fractional/reaction molecules: 3/0/0 (avg.   5.25834), density:  11.88973 (avg.  20.84008) [kg/m^3]
    absolute adsorption:   0.37500 (avg.   0.65729) [mol/uc],   0.2182616864 (avg.   0.3825646976) [mol/kg],   9.6055876881 (avg.  16.8364810584) [mg/g]
                           4.8921121458 (avg.   8.5747958536) [cm^3 STP/g],    6.0554174671 (avg.  10.6138140420) [cm^3 STP/cm^3]
    excess adsorption:     0.3741837232 (avg.   0.5327501133) [mol/uc],   0.2177865878 (avg.   0.3100771684) [mol/kg],   9.5846788380 (avg.  13.6463411439) [mg/g]
                           4.8814632982 (avg.   6.9500621330) [cm^3 STP/g],    6.0422364083 (avg.   8.6027315775) [cm^3 STP/cm^3]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and read [ask].

Comment: @AlwaysData It is not obtaining the data point, the eight value, called after the line with the leading value "TIP4P". I am trying to just single out that data point while my previous code just obtained any data for any component from the line with the leading value of "absolute".

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Without example data in your question, we cannot copy it to test a solution.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: Is that file format documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to *stay true* to your attempt.  Not sure I got the *empty lines* logic correct.

Iterate over the file till you find a line that has `'TIP4P'` in it; get the next line, split it and grab the eighth and ninth item.

```
empty = False
with open(iFileName,"r") as ifile:
    while not empty:   # keep looping till too many empty lines
        empties = 0
        line = next(ifile).strip()
        while line[13:18] != 'TIP4P':
            line = next(ifile).strip()
            #print(line)
            if not line:
               empties += 1 
            if empties >= 10:
                empty = True
                break
        if empty: break
        line = next(ifile).strip()
        line = line.split()
        #print(list(enumerate(line)))
        val = line[8][:-1]
        units = line[9][1:-2]
        val = float(val)
        print('val: {} - {}'.format(val,units))
```

---

It probably isn't the way I would do it. I would probably rely on the structure and find what I wanted with a regular expression.

```
import re
pattern = r'TIP4P.*$\s+.*?(\d+\.\d+)\)\s\[(mol/kg)'
tip4p = re.compile(pattern,flags=re.MULTILINE)

with open(iFileName,"r") as ifile:
    s = ifile.read()

for match in tip4p.finditer(s):
    #print(match.groups())
    val,units = match.groups()
    val = float(val)
    print('val: {} - {}'.format(val,units))
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on the second apostrophe in the print(f'val: {val}') line

Comment: Also how would I go about obtain the value for mol/kg do I adjust the -2 to -6?

Comment: @ArianjelHernandez - if you don't have Python 3.6+ just use `print(val)` or `print('val: {}'.format(val))`.

Comment: @ArianjelHernandez see edit, I updated both to grab the units also.  I think my previous solution was grabbing the wrong value(s) - for your example data you want `1.2303533697`??

Comment: First thing First I want to say thank you the second code works so well! I just need help with one more thing. That data is printed over time as the simulation evolves how do I get it to print the last one. @wwii

Comment: For either solution, unindent the print so that it occurs after the loop stops - `val` and `units` will be from the *last record*.

Comment: Thanks for your help a while back it has helped me immensely. I was wondering if you could help obtain the mol/kg value for co2 and it error. with the script you created. I edited the post to show where the information is at and formatted.

Comment: Thanks for your help a while back it has helped me immensely. I was wondering if you could help obtain the mol/kg value for co2 and it error. with the script you created. I edited the post to show where the information is at and formatted.

Comment: @ArianjelHernandez you should just ask a new question - the data is completely different.. Also revert the edit so the answers still pertain to the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160353/obtaining-data-from-raspa2

Comment: As you can see I am very much a noob at all of this and I greatly appreciate your time!